# Output of urllib.urlopen doesn't display when render to a template

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Python 2.7 - how can I convert the output of `urllib.urlopen` to a string?

```
data =  urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
test = "testone"
return render_to_response('home.html', locals())
```

home.html:

```
{{data}}
<br/>
{{test}}
```

Only 'testone' displays in the browser.

Comment: Have you... actually looked at the output yet?

Comment: @Jisson - What you have there is already a string... What problems are you having?

Comment: Am trying to fetch a url and try to print the o/p to the rendering template  return render_to_response('home.html', {'v1': data}) and try to print using {{v1}} in template ,But not dispaly any thing

Comment: if print (print data) in view its woks well(o/p in console),but when I pass it to template ,the o/p of urllib not displaying there

Answer (score 1):

On my system it's already a string, so no conversion is required:

```
In [4]: type(urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read())
Out[4]: <type 'str'>
```

Comment: Yea its a string, But it doesn't display when i render it to a template

Comment: data =  urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read() 
return render_to_response('home.html', locals())

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> data = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
>>> type(data)
<type 'str'>
```

It's already a string.

Answer (score 1):

when I change the url  www.example.org.Its worked.